# Running Unity3d for automated builds inside a docker container

Tags: unity-game-engine, docker

I have managed to run Unity 3d inside a container to perform a build.

For now I am specifying my serial number, email and unity account password on the command line. When running this on my local machine, just to test how it works, this is fine.

Before I do it on our cluster (where our build system runs), does anyone know if there are issues with license activation when doing this?